# Why do I get ArrayOutOfBounds exception?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm not sure why I get the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1

I'm aware the exception means there is an attempt to access an index outside of the scope of the array. However, there is no attempt to access the -1 index (Not sure if that is even possible); not that I can see anyway.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Integer> baseNum;
ListView listView;
SeekBar seekBar;

public void multiples (int multiple) {
    int p = 0; // The first index of array baseNum

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

        baseNum.set(baseNum.indexOf(p), i * multiple); // Replace current element 'p' with the new element 'i*multiple'; this should be the current progress of the seekBar
        p++;

    }

}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setMax(10);

    // Create an integer array for base numbers
    baseNum = new ArrayList<>();

    // Display multiples in ListView
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    final ArrayAdapter<Integer> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, baseNum);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

        baseNum.add(i);

    }

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) { // When progress is changed (here is where the code should be to change which base multiples show)

            int min = 1;
            int multiple = min;

            if (progress < min) {

                progress = min;
                seekBar.setProgress(progress);

            } else {

                multiple = progress;

            }

            multiples(multiple);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: The stack trace of the exception will tell you which line it happened on.

Comment: `baseNum.indexOf(p)` can return -1. So `baseNum.set(baseNum.indexOf(p), i * multiple);` would then be using -1 as an index.

Comment: *"However, there is no attempt to access the -1 index (Not sure if that is even possible); not that I can see anyway."* - It is really unwise to doubt the evidence that the error message is giving you.  If it is happening then it is definitely possible.

Comment: Why can  `baseNum.indexOf(p)` return a -1 if `p = 0`? and is incremented? @khelwood

Comment: `baseNum.indexOf(p)` returns -1 if p is 0 and `baseNum` doesn't contain 0. How about you check `baseNum` and see what it contains?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to access -1 index at

```
baseNum.set(baseNum.indexOf(p), i * multiple);
```

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-), `indexOf(Object o)` can return -1

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in
> this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.

When you try to set an element at index which is out of range. it will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`